# PHP : get height width of all image in directory

Tags: javascript, php

I am working on image directory in PHP , and i need image's height width in PHP to use in HTML, I try using javascript but it not give actual value of height width of image. Give me alternate solution of this in php or in javascript.

Comment: A combination of `glob()` and `getimagesize()` should do the trick.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For php use getimagesize() function:

```
<?php
list($width, $height, $type, $attr) = getimagesize("img/flag.jpg");
echo "<img src=\"img/flag.jpg\" $attr alt=\"getimagesize() example\" />";
?>
```